# Python posting answer from function to entry box in GUI

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to return an answer from simple addition to an entry box in Python 3.4 but keep getting the following error. Exception in Tkinter callback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1533, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "H:\guitest.py", line 12, in calculate
    enter3.configure(text=answer)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'configure'


#Imports The Default Graphical Library
import tkinter
from tkinter import *

#Addition Function
def calculate():
    """ take the two numbers entered and process them """
    firstnum=int(number1.get())

    secondnum=int(number2.get())
    answer=firstnum+secondnum
    enter3.configure(text=answer)
    return


#Creates Graphical Window
window = Tk()
# Assigns a Name To the Graphical Window
window.title("MY GUI")
# Set the Graphical Window Size
window.geometry("500x200")

number1=StringVar()
number2=StringVar()

label1 = Label(text='1st Number').place(x=50,y=30)
label2 = Label(text='2nd Number').place(x=150,y=30)
label3 = Label(text='ANSWER').place(x=100,y=80)
enter1 =Entry(width=10,textvariable=number1).place(x=50,y=50)
enter2 =Entry(width=10,textvariable=number2).place(x=150,y=50)
enter3 =Entry(width=10).place(x=100,y=100)



#Creates Button
w = Button(text='ADD',bd=10,command=calculate).place(x=100,y=150)

#Executes the above Code to Create the Graphical Window
window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

There are at least three problems here.

1. The variables that are supposed to be holding UI elements (e.g. `label1`, `entry3`) are not, in fact, holding them. They are set to `None`. The `place` method is not returning the object being placed. It's just doing the placing. So you'd need to change your initialization strategy to something like:

   ```
   enter3 = Entry(width=10)
   enter3.place(x=100,y=100)
   ```

   If you argued that non-fluid style is less graceful, I'd agree...but apparently `place` does not return the object, so you can't do *en passant* creation and placement.
2. `entry3.configure(text=answer)` is not going to work, because `answer` is not a string. It's an integer. You need `entry3.configure(text=str(answer))`. At minimum.
3. I lied. That is not going to work either, because `configure` is not how `Entry` widget text is usually set. Try instead:

   ```
   entry3.delete(0, END) # delete whatever's there already
   entry3.insert(0, str(answer))
   entry3.update() # make sure update is flushed / immediately visible
   ```

   See e.g. [this tutorial](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/entry.htm) for more on `Entry` objects. And while explicit `widget.update()` calls may look clunky, trust me--they come in super-handy when things don't update as you think they should.
4. I'm not sure why you're using a hybrid strategy. For inputs, you use `StringVar` objects, but then you shift to a raw update for the answer widget. Not that it won't work...but it might be easier just to set `number3 = StringVar()` and attach it as the `textvariable` of `entry3`, then `number3.set(str(answer))` when you want to update it. Pick your poison.

Even if you make these changes, you'll have some work to do to have a "good" Tk app, but these will at least make the updates work as they should, and get you on your way.